# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ... previously declared in

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare isitadmin() (previously declared in /home/heart.php:19) in /home/heart.php on line 37

Есть файл `index.php`, который включает файл `heart.php`. В самом `heart.php` есть функция

```
function isitadmin() 
{
    ...тут идут всякие сравнения кук и бд.  ...
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Гуглил, нашел только то, что может быть двойное обращение к функции. Попробовал убрать это. Просто вызвал функцию один раз и запомнил в переменную. Всё равно такая же проблема.

Comment: покажите листинг кода, тогда Вам покажут конкретное место ошибки.

Comment: я уже каким-то образом исправил всё) даже не понял как. Магия..что уж еще сказать

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор уже исправил ошибку и не знает каким образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите внимательно на описание ошибки.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare isitadmin() (previously declared in /home/heart.php:19) in /home/heart.php on line 37

в файле `/home/heart.php` 2 раза объявлена функция `isitadmin`

первый раз она объявлена в строке 19, второй раз в строке 37

Comment: Немного опишу функцию, ибо не понимаю чуть.
в строке 18 идет объявление функции
А , внимание, в 19ой идет условие if (существует ли cookies) {  } 
в 37 строке заканчивается функция, там стоит '}' . 
Нигде вроде не объявляется. Или я что-то не понимаю. Прошу объяснить.

Comment: Значит таки вариант что вы 2 раза подключаете heart.php 
при подключении файлов используйте `require_once`

Answer (score -1):

```
Cannot redeclare isitadmin()
```

Ответ уже написан. Не могу переопределить ф-ю. т.е. файл уже где-то подключен и повторно тоже где-то подключен.

Comment: в том то и дело, что больше нигде этот файл не вызывается в данный момент. В самом начале выполнения index.php , включил heart.php и присвоил $admin = isitadmin(). Потом уже нигде не включается эта функция. Везде только используется $admin.  Кстати isitadmin возвращает 1 или 0.

Answer (score -1):

`require_once` сделайте, где подключаете файл с функцией этой.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?